# cmake generates wrong makefiles

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

```
/usr/bin/clang++    -std=c++11;-Werror;-Wextra;-Wall;-Wconversion -g   -o CMakeFiles/TilingGame.dir/src/streak.cc.o -c /home/arne/projects/tilinggame/src/streak.cc
clang: error: no input files
/bin/sh: -Werror: Kommando nicht gefunden.
/bin/sh: -Wextra: Kommando nicht gefunden.
/bin/sh: -Wall: Kommando nicht gefunden.
/bin/sh: -Wconversion: Kommando nicht gefunden.
CMakeFiles/TilingGame.dir/build.make:54: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/TilingGame.dir/src/streak.cc.o' failed
```

as you can see my shees sees the semicolon as the end of the command and then tries to interpret  "-Werror" as a new command. How can I tell cmake to generate working makefiles instead of broken ones?

here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
project(TilingGame)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
aux_source_directory(src SRC_LIST)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -std=c++11 -Werror -Wextra -Wall -Wconversion)

include(FindPkgConfig)

PKG_SEARCH_MODULE(SDL2 REQUIRED sdl2)
PKG_SEARCH_MODULE(SDL2IMAGE REQUIRED SDL2_image)
PKG_SEARCH_MODULE(SDL2MIXER REQUIRED SDL2_mixer)
PKG_SEARCH_MODULE(SDL2TTF REQUIRED SDL2_ttf)
PKG_SEARCH_MODULE(ZLIB REQUIRED zlib)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2IMAGE_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2MIXER_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2TTF_LIBRARIES} ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES} tmxparser tinyxml)
```

Comment: Consider using [`target_compile_options`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_compile_options.html) instead of `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`. It offers better control over the scope of the flags and integrates more nicely with third-party CMake scripts.

Comment: @ComicSansMS I tried the command. The documentation has no example and all information I get when I use it is this: target compile options called with invalid arguments. So is there an example

Comment: A simple example would be `target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC -std=c++11 -Werror -Wextra -Wall -Wconversion)`. Note that this approach also works without the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only add strings/append strings to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, but not lists.

The following should work:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -Werror -Wextra -Wall -Wconversion")
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't show us the section of your cmake file where you are adding those flags we can't say exactly.  However, clearly somehow you're causing cmake to convert a list of values into a string and then using that string as flags.  The string-ified version of list variables in cmake are semicolon-separated.

For example maybe you have something like this in your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(FLAGS -std=c++11 -Werror -Wextra -Wall -Wconversion)
add_definitions("${FLAGS}")
```

You should not use the quotes here.

Comment: I added the CMakeLists.text now. Btw I also found a solution that at least works temporarily: I use quotes around all the flags.

Comment: Assuming you  mean enclosing all the flags in one set of quotes, that's the right answer.  The `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable is apparently expected to contain a string, not a list, and is quoted by cmake.